# Send email once if ping fails

Tags: vb.net, email, monitoring, ping

I'm creating a monitoring system using VB.net. I want the system to send an email if a device is down, and send an email again if that device is back to online. I use Ping to monitor the devices. The IP address of the device is already saved and will be displayed in `lvi.SubItems(5).Text`.

With the following code, the email is always sent if the device ping fails. I just want the email to be sent one time if the ping fails. Can you help me to solve the problem.

```
Private Sub Ping_LV()
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In LV_Monitoring.Items
        Dim p As New Ping
        AddHandler p.PingCompleted, AddressOf p_PingCompleted
        p.SendAsync(lvi.SubItems(5).Text, lvi)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub p_PingCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim p As Ping = DirectCast(sender, Ping)
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem = DirectCast(e.UserState, ListViewItem)

    If e.Reply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine("Ping Success")
        lvi.SubItems(6).Text = "UP"
        lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
        lvi.SubItems(6).ForeColor = Color.White
        lvi.SubItems(6).BackColor = Color.Green
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Ping Failed")
        lvi.SubItems(6).Text = "DOWN"
        lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
        lvi.SubItems(6).ForeColor = Color.White
        lvi.SubItems(6).BackColor = Color.Red
        Sent_Email()
    End If

    RemoveHandler p.PingCompleted, AddressOf p_PingCompleted
    p.Dispose()
    LV_Monitoring.Refresh()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    Ping_LV()
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Monitoring_Devices_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: You could test the current `Text` of the item and only send the notification if it isn't "DOWN" already.  I'd probably rather use a dedicated Boolean flag though, which you could perhaps store in the `Tag` of the item.

Comment: I dont quite understand that, would you like to show me an example code for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way is just to keep the state of sent mail in a variable or property.
 So the first time ping fails and email is sent, you set the variable/property to true and when your pc goes online again you reset it. You also could use for example a dictionary if you prefer a collection to keep track of this.

As requested an example:

```
    Dim mailSent As New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)
Dim ipList As New List(Of String) From {"192.168.192.1", "192.168.192.110", "192.168.192.105"}

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each ip In ipList
        Dim p As New Ping
        AddHandler p.PingCompleted, AddressOf PingCompleted
        p.SendAsync(ip, ip)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PingCompleted(sender As Object, e As PingCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim p = DirectCast(sender, Ping)
    Dim ip = DirectCast(e.UserState, String)

    If e.Reply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
        If mailSent.Item(ip) Then
            mailSent.Item(ip) = False
        End If
    Else
        If Not mailSent.Item(ip) Then
            Console.WriteLine(ip & " is offline")
            mailSent.Item(ip) = True
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("You know already " & ip & "state")
        End If
    End If
    RemoveHandler p.PingCompleted, AddressOf PingCompleted
    p.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each ip As String In ipList
        mailSent.Add(ip, False)
    Next
End Sub
```

Thats an **example**, you should work it out to get what you need :)

Comment: Would you like to show me the example code for this case. Because I have tried to do that before, it work if the Ping fails on 1 PC or IP Address, it will sent an email once the ping fails. But if the second PC goes down after that, it will not sent an email.

Comment: Example added, its not 1:1 what you need, but you should understand what you could do.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot brother, I have tried that and it successfull.